# Elastic search deep tree model

Tags: elasticsearch, tree

I’m researching for database tool, and i’m not quite sure how Elastic can cope with my requirements.

I have a tree data structure, a family tree.

The root is the first man Adam, and afterward his children, there children and so on.

Elements looks like this (don't care about marriage relations this data just to get the idea) :

```
{
  id: 1
  name: “Adam”
  parentId: 0
}, {
  id: 2
  name: “Cain”
  parentId: 1
}, {
  id: 3
  name: “Abel”
  parentId: 1
}, {
  id: 4
  name: “johnny(Cain junior)”
  parentId: 2
}, … {
  id: 12324568
  name: “Cain b”
  parentId: 1434
}
```

Queries I’d like to exec:

1. ‘full text’ search on the element name, response should include the documents and the path to them. Fof example, searching for ‘Cain’ should replay:

   a. Adam/Cain

   b.  ../David/Danny/Cain b
2. CRUD person by id (Ids are unique)
3. Get family tree by id, will respond hierarchical tree (nested JSON) , from ‘id’ as root
4. Tree is about ~20-30 level deep, up to 10,000 elements

Finally, my question:

1. Can elasticsearch provide me this functionality?
2. Should i use the parent/child scheme?
3. How should the index mapping should look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions:

3) Your index mapping could look something like this:

```
 {
  "mappings": {
    "my_index": {
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "integer",
          "fielddata": true <-- you need this if you're using this field for aggregations
        },
        "parentId": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "text" <-- can be text/keyword depending on your requirement
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2) I would suggest you to use the [parent-child](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/parent-child.html#parent-child) mapping, so that you can have a *one-to-many* relationship. Elasticsearch maintains a map of how parents correspond with their children, and query-time joins are fast because of this mapping. You could read up on this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939078/scaling-with-regard-to-nested-vs-parent-child-documents) to know the benchmark of parent-child mapping over the *nested*.

1) You could always do a `full text` search as long as you have your mapping **type** for your field as **text**. [This](https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings) should help you on identifying the difference of using the type `text` over `keyword`. You could add a single document to your index or else you could go with a [bulk](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) adding containing multiple documents. This goes hand in hand with other *CRUD* operations as well. I'm still unaware how the hierarchical tree would respond when you're requesting documents by a parent id.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Darth_Vader, it is helping
after reading your answer I have follow up question:
how can I use Parent/child here,
If I understood correctly, It not allowing to create n-level tree of the same type "my_index" ?
                                                                                                                May the(dark side of)  Force be with you :)