# Why is querying slower for parent/child relationships versus when using nested documents?

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

Queries on parent/child structures that were created using the join_field are considered slower than querying on nested documents. The general explication that I found was that in the first case the queries are slower because the child is stored separately from the parent. Still, I would like to have a fuller picture on why this is happening. I have read that in case of nested documents Elasticsearch actually indexes root object and nested objects separately, then relates them internally. I have also read that in this case the documents are stored in the same Lucene block and this makes queries faster. But still...how does the inverted index look exactly in case of nested documents versus parent/child?

Comment: This answer may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14941912/5095957. Also this forum thread: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/choosing-parent-child-vs-nested-document/6742/12

Comment: Indeed, very helpful